# Rebuilding grub with LVM2 and UEFI

Tags: boot, grub, uefi, ubuntu-22.04, lvm2

Trying to restore my grub boot loader for Ubuntu 22.04, but a weird anomaly during the rebuild process changes the boot menu to CentOS. I have tried several rebuild attempts from many different sources including superuser. Below is the latest process I attempted by combining techniques from several different sources (booting from a Live Ubuntu memory stick):

- Ensure LVM2 is installed

  ```
   apt install lvm2
   modprobe dm-mod
   fdisk -l
  ```
- Find the device with the LVM partition, in my case: `/dev/nvme0n1p3`

  ```
   uname -m
  ```
- Ensure that the current operating x86 versus x86_64 matches the operating system you are trying to repair

  ```
   lvscan
   lvdisplay
   mkdir /mnt/home
   mkdir /mnt/root
   mount /dev/new_name/home /mnt/home
   mount /dev/new_name/root /mnt/root
  ```
- Initialize your swap partition if necessary:

  ```
   swapon /dev/new_name/swap
   mount --bind /run /mnt/root/run
   mount --bind /mnt/home /mnt/root/home
   mkdir /mnt/boot
   mount /dev/nvme0n1p1 /mnt/boot
   mount --bind /mnt/boot /mnt/root/boot/efi
   for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt/root/$i; done
   chroot /mnt/root /bin/bash
   grub-install --recheck /dev/nvme0n1
  ```

Results:

```
   Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
   grub-install: warning: EFI variables cannot be set on this system.
   grub-install: warning: You will have to complete the GRUB setup manually.
   Installation finished. No error reported.
```

After that:

```
update-grub
exit
```

After rebooting... still getting boot CentOS for the grub menu, and still get the warning messages:

> /dev/centos/root, /dev/centos/swap, and /dev/mapper/centos-root does not exist.

Then the boot process enters emergency mode and generates the `rdsosreport.txt` file.
I have the report... but do not see a way to attach it.

Any tips on getting my grub to recognize Ubuntu? BTW, I did mount a CentOS 7 LVM2 partition previously trying to look at some data I was trying to save. I was able to mount it successfully... hoping that process did not cause these anomalies.

Appreciate any help :)

Comment: Thanks for the edits zx485 :)